# how to fix error setBeamPushUris?

Tags: android, eclipse, nfc

I want to find way for fix error([image]) i used android 4  API Level 14,the following code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

            adapter.setBeamPushUris(null, this);
        }
```

for Use this code ,Please Help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you change the build target, this should compile.

```
In Project -> properties -> Android-> Select 4.1
```

Edit: Also your condition is incorrect. this api was introduced in JellyBean so

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
```

Comment: i have Xpria P (android 4.0.4)API level 15 i cant update android OS to 4.1 and test project

Comment: The above setting is just for compilation. The code is compiled against jelly bean apis.  It does not change the working. you can still test it on xperia but not this api

Comment: Are you sure Donwload API Level 16 fix problem ?I Changed above code to this   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {adapter.setNdefPushMessage(null, this);} i think fix Problem

Comment: not just download, you need to change the properties of your project too, like i have described